# Ubuntu 18.04 + Radeon RX 580 Drivers

Tags: 18.04, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu, gpu-driver

**The Issue:**

I don't seem to be able to install the Radeon Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

**Attempt One:**

Downloaded drivers from AMD's page [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux).

Ran the following commands:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-install -y
sudo reboot
```

Once back into Ubuntu, the desktop and even youtube video's were rendering slowly.  As if the CPU was being used instead of the GPU.

---

**Attempt Two:**

Ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && \
sudo apt update && \
sudo apt upgrade && \
sudo apt autoremove && \
sudo apt autoclean
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 ubuntu-session xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers
sudo reboot
```

Once back into the desktop, the whole desktop and even youtube videos were still rendering slowly, as if the CPU was being used instead of the GPU.

---

**Attempt Three:**

Ran the following commands:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install -y
sudo reboot
```

Ubuntu no longer gets to the login screen.  Shows the following message:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clearn, 428119/15155200 files, 35460694/60609536 blocks
```

---

**Other Info:**

[image]

Before I got the RX 580, I had an old Nvidia GT 520 and I had to have nomodeset in the grub config file.  When installing the Radeon drivers, I get a message saying:

```
WARNING: nomodeset detected in kernel parameters, amdgpu requires KMS
```

So I remove nomodeset from the grub, reboot, and then I am no longer able to access the desktop.  If I put the nomodeset back into the grub config file, I can then get back into the desktop.

---

**The Question:**

Now that I have managed to get back into Ubuntu, how do I remove any residue of the amdgpu-pro driver and anything else that I should not have done from the above attempts, remove the nvidia drivers for the previously installed gpu, and then try installing the amd drivers again to get the RX 580 working on Ubuntu 18.04?  Tried and tested on Windows 10 (used bios boot options to boot into a second SSD which has Windows 10 installed) and the GPU works perfectly after installing the drivers on Windows 10.  So it's not a hardware problem with the GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first link isn't the only one provided by AMD. This page has separate AMD GPU drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04:

- [Radeon™ Software for Linux® 18.40 Highlights](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-40)

On the same page you will find links to instructions tailored for Linux users:

- [Radeon™ Software for Linux® Installation](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Within the instruction section you'll find a link for reporting bugs:

- [Generating a Bug Report](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-bugrep.html)

This could be your best friend because even operating on CPU's iGPU alone there shouldn't be any lagging with youtube videos.

Comment: Got it working.  I think the lagging of youtube videos was because I have a 1st gen i3 CPU.  However, now that the Radeon card is working properly, the desktop is smooth as butter, youtube too and getting between 60 to 300 fps depending on the game chosen.