# After upgrading from 21.04 to 21.10 I get a blank login screen

Tags: boot, login

GUI seems to be partially working. I get a clock, accessibility and power settings, but rest of the screen is just solid purple colour, no user to select no field to enter my password so that I can actually login.

I have checked if I can get terminal access with ctrl + alt + F1-F8 but I had no luck with that.

I have tried also tried reinstalling gdm3 from root console in recovery mode, but that didn't help.

```
apt install --reinstall gdm3 ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell
```

One way I managed to get in is by waiting until the display is automatically turned off, I don't know if that refreshes gdm3 or something.

edit:
installing lightdm allows me to login without waiting but I would rather fix gdm3

```
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Comment: What computer model are you working with?

Comment: It's my desktop. Gigabyte B450 AORUS M, AMD Ryzen 5600X, Radeon RX 480

Comment: Are you using wayland?  There have been known issues with it.  If so try switching to xorg and see if the problem persists.

Comment: I would also check here https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-10  which came from this source but for 18.04 and a different radeon card https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195207/ubuntu-18-04-radeon-rx-580-drivers

Comment: Check your logs? Look at your upgrade in /var/log/apt for errors and other messages that occurred during your release-upgrade.Your logs may be a rich source of useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having the same issue. i5-6600 and GTX 1070. I disabled wayland, no change. But when I set my account to auto login, it does so, so I can get in for now. If I log out, the login screen does show and I can log back in. There is just no login screen at boot. Just the clock, network and power icons.

edit: Auto login is in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file if you need to do it from the command prompt in the recovery boot.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an answer, or an "I'm having this issue too" post.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first comment. It wouldn't let me comment directly to the question since I don't have 50 reputation. I also don't see an "I'm having this issue too" option. But...I think I did find the issue. Digging though syslog, I saw that the Fingerprint Service wasn't loading, I'd never messed around with the Fingerprint options since I don't have a finger print reader. You can look for Fprint in syslog and see if there are service loading errors. One "apt purge fprintd" and the issue is gone and everything boots correctly. I hope that helps. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please [edit] and update your answer with the full details *if* you think it is a solution. Don't put additional info in the comments, that is not what they are for. Yes, you need [50 rep to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/280335). The "I'm having this issue too" is an option in the review queue only, when your post could be deleted for being such - hence why you need to update your answer fully. HTH.